# How to create a NXN matrix using for loop in python

Tags: python, list, matrix

I am kind new to python, and trying to create a dice example for CLT (central limit theory) as follows

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

SampleSize=1000000
NumberofDice=2

Dice=np.zeros([SampleSize,NumberofDice])

for i in range(NumberofDice+1):
 Dice[:,i]=np.random.randint(1,7,SampleSize)
```

but I had an error saying

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 11, in
>    IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2

I am not sure how to deal with it, basically I want to create a 2 X 1000000 matrix, and each row is an independent rolling dice process.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

`range(NumberofDice+1)` just remove that `+1`, numpy indexing is `0` to `n-1`, not `1` to `n`, and `range` also follows that convention.

By the way you could do it directly like so too:

```
Dice = np.random.randint(1,7,size=(SampleSize,NumberofDice))
```